# Can we conditionally render text in a non-Visualforce email template on a picklist?

Tags: email-template, formula

I'm working on designing an HTML template as a possible workaround to a problem with Visualforce templates refusing to send when triggered from a workflow rule where the ownership changes, and the old owner can no longer see the record.

Part of the reason we were using a Visualforce template is because we are emitting tabular details about the record whose ownership is changing. Currently, it looks like this:

```
Label A: {!FieldA}
Label B: {!FieldB}
Label C: {!FieldC}
<apex:outputText rendered="{!FieldD!=null}">Label D: {!FieldD}</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!FieldE!=null}">Label E: {!FieldE}</apex:outputText>
```

FieldD is a picklist, and it works fine in the Visualforce template. Unfortunately, when I try to build a similar construct in a non-Visualforce template, it fails to run. By that, I mean it doesn't output anything at all, as if the formula were invalid (so perhaps they are?).

```
{!IF(ISPICKVAL(FieldD,''), '', 'Label D: ' & TEXT(FieldD))}
{!IF(ISNULL(TEXT(FieldD)), '', 'Label D: ' & TEXT(FieldD))}
{!IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(FieldD)), '', 'Label D: ' & TEXT(FieldD))}
```

All three of these constructs work in a normal formula field, but none of them work in the email template. Is there a way we can make this work?

*Bonus Question* Is there a way to conditionally render an newline in a text email template merge area?

*Edit* I should mention that I could, in theory, do this by merging in a formula field, but that would really be a final resort, especially since I feel we should be able to accomplish this task without needing to create additional fields.

Comment: Double check the real email template's payload (download them to Eclipse or query them from `EmailTemplate` table). The online editor loves to screw up formulas, inject `<span>` and other crap into logic merge fields, messing them up. I've built some templates like that in previous work and Marketing Manager "helped" me later on by slightly modifying them in Word, pasting back to the editor... Real mess. Also - is this a straightforward picklist on "this" object or are you going "up"? Std. templates support only Id & Name when going "up"...

Comment: @eyescream The workflow triggers on opportunity, the field in question is also at the opportunity level. We use `{!Account.Field}` to access account fields, and there's no problem there. Just this one picklist.